# Javascript function not working properly because of another interfering function

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slideshow

I got 2 functions, in javascript. One is for managing an automatic slideshow (handles the hiding and showing of images, their order and revolving speed). The other is to create a fade effect, that is applied to all elements if they are scrolled outside of an area.

When scrolling up and down it seems like the slideshow function does not increment the counter variable 'i' as expected. It gets stuck at a certain number and then returns an error stating that the slideshow image element is null.

I would like help with how to solve this problem. If my question is ambiguous please tell me. Also, I no apparent answer can be had with the provided code please check out the website at www.ggraphics.byethost7.com

Here is my code:

```js
//Slideshow script//

'use strict';

var firstPicture = document.getElementById("1");
var picture = firstPicture;
var currentpic = picture;
var i = 1;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", theDomHasLoaded, false);

function rotateImages() {
      picture.className = 'slideImg2';
  
    // choose who is the next element
    if (i > document.getElementById("imgContain").childElementCount) {
      i = 1;
      picture = firstPicture;
      picture.className = 'slideImg';
    } else {
        picture = document.getElementById("imgContain").children[i-1];
        picture.className = 'slideImg';
        i++;
        
        currentpic = picture;
    }

    // show the next element
    
};

function theDomHasLoaded(e) {
  firstPicture = document.getElementById("1");
  picture = firstPicture;
  picture.className = 'slideImg';
  i = 1;

  setInterval(rotateImages, 1000);
};
```

```js
//ScrollFade script//

var opacity_names = [];
var opacity_contain = [];

function getElements(item){  //item refers to the scrollbox or scrollable element that is parent to fading elements.
  var parent = document.getElementById(item.id);
  var el_overflowb = [];
  var el_overflowt = [];
  if (parent.children.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < parent.childElementCount; i++) {
      var low_diff = Math.round(parent.children[i].offsetTop + parent.children[i].offsetHeight - parent.offsetHeight - parent.scrollTop);
      var high_diff = Math.round(parent.children[i].offsetTop - parent.scrollTop);
      if (low_diff > 0) {
        var temp = window.getComputedStyle(parent.children[i]).getPropertyValue("opacity");
        el_overflowb.push([parent.children[i].id, low_diff, temp]);
        if (opacity_names.indexOf(parent.children[i].id) == -1) {
          opacity_names.push(parent.children[i].id);
          opacity_contain.push(temp);
        }
      }
      
      if (high_diff < 0) {
        var temp1 = window.getComputedStyle(parent.children[i]).getPropertyValue("opacity");
        el_overflowt.push([parent.children[i].id, high_diff, temp1]);
        if (opacity_names.indexOf(parent.children[i].id) == -1) {
          opacity_names.push(parent.children[i].id);
          opacity_contain.push(temp1);
        }
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < el_overflowb.length; i++) {
      var h = document.getElementById(el_overflowb[i][0]).offsetHeight;
      if (el_overflowb[i][1] <= h) { 
        var pos = h - el_overflowb[i][1];
        document.getElementById(el_overflowb[i][0]).style.opacity = opacity_contain[opacity_names.indexOf(el_overflowb[i][0])] * (pos / h);
      }else{
        document.getElementById(el_overflowb[i][0]).style.opacity = 0;
      }
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < el_overflowt.length; i++) {
      var h = document.getElementById(el_overflowt[i][0]).offsetHeight;
      if (el_overflowt[i][1] >= -h) { 
        var pos = h + el_overflowt[i][1];
        document.getElementById(el_overflowt[i][0]).style.opacity = opacity_contain[opacity_names.indexOf(el_overflowt[i][0])] * (pos / h);
      }else{
        document.getElementById(el_overflowt[i][0]).style.opacity = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use global namespace, especially for variable like `i`.

Add `var i` to `function getElements(item)`, this should create new instance of it inside script.

Comment: And it would be better for you if use namespace for `//Slideshow script//`

Comment: Thanks that seemed to have solved my problem, you saved me from a big headache!